# erb: iterate over array of hashes

Tags: arrays, hash, puppet, erb

I have hiera data in puppet like below:

```
myservers:
  - serverA:
      propertyA: valueA
      propertyB: valueB
      propertyC: valueC
  - serverB:
      propertyA: valueD
      propertyB: valueE
```

The configuration file from this data should print out like:

```
serverA:  PropertyA: valueA ; propertyB: valueB ; propertyC: valueC
serverB:  PropertyA: valueD ; propertyB: valueE
```

I am attempting to put this in erb template, by iterating over the array of hashes, but can't get formatted correctly.

```
<% myservers.each do |server| -%>
<%= server -%>: <%= server.each do |k,v| -%> <%= k -%>: <%= v -%> ;
<% end %>
<% end -%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you meant to write is:

```
<% @myservers.each do |server| -%>
<% server.keys.each do |s| -%>
<%= s %>: <% server[s].each do |k,v| -%><%= k -%>: <%= v -%> ;<% end %>
<% end -%>
<% end -%>
```

Or perhaps (if you know each array element will contain only one server, as in your example):

```
<% @myservers.each do |server| -%>
<%= server.keys[0] %>: <% server[server.keys[0]].each do |k,v| -%><%= k -%>: <%= v -%> ;<% end %>
<% end -%>
```

In words, you are treating what is really an Array of Hash of Hashes as an Array of Hashes.

Also, variables in Puppet manifests appear as instance variables inside ERB templates, thus the `@`. See [here](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/4.10/lang_template_erb.html#accessing-puppet-variables).

Comment: An explanation to go with the code fixes would really improve the answer quality.

Comment: I am not sure that putting words around this helps much, but anyhow, updated.

Comment: Ok, updated again with an explanation about Puppet variables being passed as instance variables in ERB templates.